# Defining dedicated dispatcher in Akka Stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream

Just wondering where a dispacther should be defined in application.conf.

I red contradictory things online and the official akka documentation does not specify it.

Where should a custom dispatcher be defined in application.conf?

In the root of the file ?

In akka{} ?

In akka.actor {} ?

I am not really sure, of the proper way ?

Also if it is in the root of the file, how does akka, know how to detect that a dispatcher is being defined ?

Not that my application is a pure akka-stream application, and i do not not create actor explicitly, but rather let akka-stream do it. I need some dedicated dispatcher for some specific stage of my stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your dispatcher in the root of the file.
there are several ways to define, which actor use which dispatcher.
[this page](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#setting-the-dispatcher-for-an-actor) will show you how to define a custom dispatcher and how to use them as a system "global" dispatcher and for specified actors with a config or while spawn actors.